# Permissions failure with Execution API from Android app

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I am able to successfully get the [Execution API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/target-script) to work for accessing filenames.

But augmenting the Quickstart script to use Spreadsheet functions triggers an error of type "No authentication challenges found".

The addition of `DriveApp.getFilesByName()` does not cause any permissions problems, it is the addition of `SpreadsheetApp.create()` that triggers the error. Saving the augmented script generates a message that the script requires additional permissions. I have tried:

- creating/saving a new/complete script so all required permissions are established with the first script instantion
- deleting the app data on the target to force new permissions to be granted
- deleting the app on the target to force new permissions to be granted
- regenerating a new SHA1 key and re-credential-ing with the new key to re-initiate the permission granting process

My code:

```js
function getFoldersUnderRoot() {
  var my_ss = "SDRP-Log-Test";
  var my_sheet = "month";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(my_ss);
  var file = !files.hasNext() ? SpreadsheetApp.create(my_ss) : files.next();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folders = root.getFolders();
  var folderSet = {};
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderSet[folder.getId()] = folder.getName();
  }
  return folderSet;
}
```

I have independently verified that the Spreadsheet scripting works correctly via the development interface, so the scripting works.

`build.gradle`:

```js
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jackb.sdrp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Development platform:

- Host: Win10 & Android Studio 1.4 (Current patching)

Target:

- Samsung Galaxy S2 & Android 4.1.2
- Samsung Galaxy S5 & Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding SpreadsheetApp calls, you've modified the authentication scope required for your script. You need to update your scope to include Spreadsheets.

> To use the API, you must supply a [valid OAuth token](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#authorization) that covers all the scopes used by the script (not just the ones used by the called function). To find the correct scopes to include in the authentication token, open the project in the script editor, then select **File > Project properties** and click the **Scopes** tab.<sup>[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad.  Response was necessary but insufficient, the part I couldn't figure out was how to provide the additional scopes, which I since determined was by appending to MainActiivty.java:private: static final `String[] SCOPES = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" };`  I was expecting a app level property to reside in AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle, etc and was looking in all the wrong places.  I struggle with  Google "documentation".