# App Script Go Quickstart modification 401 error

Tags: go, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying out this tutorial on [Go and App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/go) and it works perfectly but the moment I modified the code to access a spreadsheet the go part doesn't execute the script but give a 401 error. Here is my go code (basically code from the tutorial but changed a few things for it to 'work' on my app script) http://pastebin.com/28S5tVY2

I don't know if I made a mistake when creating credentials for the script (I have redone this severally with no success) or if I missed something while doing the modification. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33548808/1677912); when you start using a different service in your script you need to get new authentication scope that covers them.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad. Adding the spreadsheet scope worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Mogsdad, I looked into adding scopes. On the target App Script, click on File >> Project Properties >> Scopes to get what scopes you need to add. An example of a scope is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets".

On the Golang code, add the scope like so:

```
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
```

Hope this helps someone :)