# Google Execution API with Simple Access API key to access AUTHORS spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

From what I understand, deploying a Google Script as a Google Execution API allows me to call each function from my script separately as and when I need it.

I have a webpage with some buttons and forms that I want to run the functions within my script on.

I have a Google Script with some (example) functionality:

```
function addPlayer(name,email,group) {
  //name email group
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID); //Sheet belonging to me, script author.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Players");

  sheet.appendRow(new Date(),name,email,group);

}

function updatePlayer() {
  //update player row with new data
  //name email group

}

function anotherFunction() {
  //store some data in another sheet within spreadsheet.    
}

function listPlayers()
{
    //return data from sheet
}
```

And a sample webpage which wants to run functions from that script:

```
function OnLoadCallback() { //on gapi load

  gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY); //developer dashboard generated browser API key 

  // Create execution request.
  var request = {
    'function': 'addPlayer',
    'parameters': [name,email,group],
    'devMode': true  
  };

  // Make the request.
  var op = gapi.client.request({
  'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
  'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
  'method': 'POST',
  'body': request
 });
}
```

I get a 401 UNAUTHENTICATED error at the moment saying I do not have valid auth credentials.

Is it possible for this webpage to use the API without requiring each webpage visitor to oAuth (which doesn't make sense to me as it's not THEIR data/sheet I am trying to access but my own? I know if I deploy as web app I can set it to execute AS me, but is there any similar equivalent for the Execution API?

I chose to use execution script as I need to be able to run several different functions, and as a webapp my only option would be the doPost() which wouldn't let me differentiate adding to sheets/updating sheets/reading from sheets easily?

Am I missing something completely here? If this is entirely the wrong approach I would be super grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535653/permissions-failure-with-execution-api-from-android-app), by adding SpreadsheetApp calls, you've modified the authentication scope required for your script. You need to update your scope to include Spreadsheets.

To use the API, you must supply a valid OAuth token that covers all the scopes used by the script. To find the correct scopes to include in the authentication token, open the project in the script editor, then select File > Project properties and click the Scopes tab.

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#authorization) for the list of OAuth scope.

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419614/google-apps-script-and-execution-api-latest-version-of-script-throws-error) for more information.